google oauth2 scopes and consent dialog UI
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#google-sign-in
if I fire off the consent WITHOUT the scopes 'profile' and 'email'. I will still get the UI.
Saying "By continuing, Google will share your name, email address, language preference, and profile picture with "
Is there anyway to avoid this text? It is important for my users to know that I am not learning.
Their email address:
example (.net)
options.Scope.Remove("profile");
options.Scope.Remove("email");
options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me");


By default sign-in uses the openid scope.
Which is the same as adding the profile and email scope.
If you don't want to see that message then you have to stop using sign-in.  Sign-in requires that your application knows the users profile and email info.
useful documentation

scopes#google-sign-in
openid-connect

